# Improve the way to replace the items of a List(Of String) inherited class?

Tags: vb.net, linq, list, inheritance, ienumerable

I have a class defined in this way, which inherits from a `List(Of String)` and I have some methods that needs to replace the entire list of items:

```
class something : Inherits List(Of String)

    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Public Sub Trim(Optional ByVal trimChars As Char() = Nothing)

        Dim tmpList As New List(Of String)((From line As String In Me 
                                            Select line.Trim(trimChars)).ToList)

        Me.Clear()
        Me.AddRange(tmpList)

    End Sub

end class
```

Or this else avoiding LINQ usage:

```
Public Sub Trim(Optional ByVal trimChars As Char() = Nothing)

    Dim tmpList As New List(Of String)
    For Each item As String In Me
        tmpList.Add(item.Trim(trimChars))
    Next item

    Me.Clear()
    Me.AddRange(tmpList)

End Sub
```

But I think that clearing the items and adding new ones could not be the most efficient way if we are talking about huge list of items.

Then, I would like to improve the part where I do the replacament for example instead of clearing the items and adding the new items, I could access the underlying collection or other approach to do in in a proper way by improving the performance of this logic?.

**EDIT:**

Maybe this logic could be the most efficient?

```
Public Sub Trim(Optional ByVal trimChars As Char() = Nothing)

    For index As Integer = 0 To (Me.Count - 1)
        Me(index) = Me(index).Trim(trimChars)
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For huge lists then your example (see below) is more efficient in terms of memory use as you're avoiding the need a second huge list

```
For index As Integer = 0 To (Me.Count - 1)
    Me(index) = Me(index).Trim(trimChars)
Next
```

For small lists it doesn't really matter which approach you take. The advantage of creating a second list and assigning at the end is that it treats the trimming of all strings in the list as an autonomous operation; that is, if an exception occurs, the strings in the list remain in their original condition.

You could consider an approach that returns a new list:

```
    class something : Inherits List(Of String)

        <DebuggerStepThrough>
        Public Function Trim(Optional ByVal trimChars As Char() = Nothing)

            Dim list As New something
            For index As Integer = 0 To (Me.Count - 1)
               String s = Me(index);
               If s IsNot Nothing Then
                   list.Add(s.Trim(trimChars))
               End If
            Next
            Return list;
        End Function

    end class
```

Also, you might want to consider checking for the string not being nothing (null) before calling Trim() otherwise you'll get an exception.